# Cherokee URL Rewrite

Tags: debian, cherokee

I wasn't able to find any documentation on Cherokee rewrite for .php endings. Essentially I want to remove the .php on all my pages. For example: /volunteer loads /volunteer.php but doesn't show the .php. Is this possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This would be de facto if you were using an MVC framework. If you are just using straight php and just want to obscure which language you are using, you can change the php parser extension. For example, you could name everything .html and have php parse .html files. I can post follow up settings for apache/php if that's what you want.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for the reply. What would you recommend? It's just a bit of a pain to type http://domain.com/contact.php instead of just domain.com/contact . Thanks.

Comment: I have Cherokee so if you could let me know how to do that, that would be great. Or if anyone else has a solution please let me know. I don't know all the ins and outs of the Cherokee GUI. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The below is the wrong way of doing things. You'll want to do a rewrite rule.

http://www.cherokee-project.com/doc/modules_handlers_redir.html